# zh-Hant.lproj folder in project changes to zh-hant.lproj in .app bundle

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

While testing localization for my app I discovered that Xcode changes the traditional Chinese .lproj folder name from zh-Hant.lproj to zh-hant.lproj (notice lower case 'h') in the app bundle.  Since the correct form for traditional Chinese is zh-Hant.lproj, localization won't work when the user changes their device's language to traditional Chinese therefore I have to manually load localizations when this language is set.

**quick summary**

folder name as seen in project:zh-Hant.lproj

folder name as seen in bundle/.app file after building:zh-hant.lproj

Why do you suppose Xcode is changing the name of this folder and of course, the most obvious question: how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: interesting … this is not what i see in the .ipa of mine that i just looked at.  i am sorry to be pedantic, but … have you tried performing a Clean?  have you tried removing the app from the device before trying to run again?  i have sometimes had to remove the project from my organizer to get rid of the DerivedData cache so it would be as clean as necessary.  in any case, what you're seeing should not be happening.  hopefully some cleaning and re-building will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I now know why this is happening.  Please see my submitted answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! I'm writing a framework which has its own localizations and turns out the app which was integrating my framework had its own localizations too, where traditional Chinese was set to zh-hant therefore even thought Xcode placed the framework's  .strings file and app's .strings file in the same folder (framework's is called FrameworkLocalizable.strings  while app uses default Localizable.strings), I guess Xcode has to decide which .lproj folder name to use when creating the folder for the bundle and the app's name wins.

Answer (score -1):

It should be ZH_Hant or ZH_Hans - underscore.

Comment: Are you sure of that?  zh-Hant and zh-Hans seem to be the suggested way.